# Why is getElementById returning null

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

When I press on an image I want to add a class to another HTML element.

**HTML :**

```
<img src="images/hamburger_menu.svg" alt="Hamburger menu" class="header__hamburger" id="hamburger-menu">
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
var navigation_bar = document.getElementById('nav');
var isChecked = false;
var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!isChecked){
        navigation_bar.classList.add("show");
    }
});
```

On Firefox I get TypeError: hamburger is null when I add addEventListener to the element. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a Codepen?

Comment: Most likely the problem: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the event listener after the element is created. So, use `window.onload` :

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var navigation_bar = document.getElementById('nav');
    var isChecked = false;
    var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu");

    hamburger.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(!isChecked){
            navigation_bar.classList.add("show");
            console.log("ok")
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<img src="images/hamburger_menu.svg" alt="Hamburger menu" class="header__hamburger" id="hamburger-menu">
<div id = 'nav'>nav</div>
```